# Class python error

Tags: python

Original class program:

```
 from Circle import circle
 class circle:
    def __init__(self,radius=1):  #write def __init__(self,radius=1) to set a value
        self.radius=radius
    # constructer constructs the object and initializes it

    def getArea(self):
        return(3.142*self.radius*self.radius)

    def getPerimeter(self):
        return(2*3.142*self.myradius)
```

Using class:

```
def main():
    c1=circle()
    #If below happens
    c1.radius=-1
    #if above happens then negative value will be returned
    c2=circle(5)
    c3=circle(3)
    print(c1.getArea())
    print(c2.getArea())
    print(c3.getArea())

main()
```

I was just trying to learn about classes in python. When I run the program it says that

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'circle' object has no attribute 'getArea'
```

I am not able to understand why it is happening.

Comment: Are you certain your indentation is correct? I corrected indentation in this post assuming that you just had trouble with how to post, but it could be that the `getArea()` method is not seen as part of the `circle` class. Also, why are you importing `Circle.circle` then overriding it with a new class?

Comment: use `math.pi` instead of defining pi yourself.

Comment: Why are you importing circle and the re-defining it?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I do not know why that is happening. This is how the professor taught us.

Comment: Apart from the strange import on top, your code seems to run perfectly. Note that indentation is **very important** in python. A stray space or confusing tabs and spaces **will** make your code behave incorrectly.

Comment: `from Circle import circle` is useless if you then immediately redefine `circle`. This cannot be how you were taught to do things.

Comment: @tripleee yes it was and is being right now too.

Comment: Tell whomever you are learning from that the Interwebs says they are wrong. Yes, Interwebs.

Comment: More likely you were told that once you have `class circle` in `Circle.py` you can use `import` from *other* Python programs to be able to run that code without writing it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
from math import pi

class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius=1):
        self.radius=radius

    def get_area(self):
        return pi * self.radius**2

    def get_circumvention(self):
        return 2 * pi * self.radius


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1=Circle()
    #If below happens
    c1.radius=-1
    #if above happens then negative value will be returned
    c2=Circle(5)
    c3=Circle(3)
    print(c1.get_area())
    print(c2.get_area())
    print(c3.get_area())
    print(c1.get_circumvention())
    print(c2.get_circumvention())
    print(c3.get_circumvention())
```

The error you are seeing is probably because you have that weird import statement on top that hides your circle class (you try to call `Circle.circle.getArea()` that does not exists)

Furthermore:

- [python coded styles](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggest CapsWords for class names and
  lowercase for methods and functions.
- `self.myradius` is not defined in `__init__` so getPerimeter will fail.
- The brackets in the methods are not necessary.
- `math` has `pi`
- To the power is noted as `**` (5**2 == 25)
- Use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` construct if you only want to execute when directly run and not on import.
- Perimeter -> circumvention
- Use the `import` statement in *another* python file that you want to use the `Circle` class in: `from whateveryounamedthisfile import Circle`. Then you can use `Circle` like you would in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Your import is pointless. Don't import 'circle' from 'Circle' if you, as the comments have stated. Also, you have not defined the 'myradius' attribute, therefore your 'getPerimeter()' function will not work unless you change that.